# Searching data by date - error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm using my VB.Net program to query a database in MS Access.  In the database, I have a table that contain a "question_start" (Date/Time) field.

I would like to return the IDs of each record that occur on or after a date that I choose in my VB programme.

The data in the Access table, is being stored as Date/Time under a General Date format (e.g. '10/10/2016 15:48:01').

In VB.NEt, I am using the DateTimePicker object to select the date.

Below is the code I'm using to bring back all records that have a Start Date of 10/10/2016 (10th October 2016).

*(Note 1: I have removed the time element from this particular search as I do not need my results to be time-sensitive here but are required later.)*

```vb
Private Sub btnDateText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDateText.Click

    Dim dt_QuestionDate As New DataTable()

    dt_QuestionDate = getData("SELECT question_id
                    FROM tblQuestion                     
                    WHERE question_start => " & dtDateText.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & ""
                    )

    lstDateText.DataSource = dt_QuestionDate
    lstDateText.DisplayMember = "question_id"
    lstDateText.ValueMember = "question_id"

End Sub
```

**There are records in my database that should be returned, but I am receiving no values currently.  I am not sure if it is how I've written the WHERE clause (I've done WHERE with "=>", ">=", and also "=") but I am not receiving records with the 10/10/2016.

Has anyone any ideas please?  I don't know if it's because it's a simple mistake, or because of the time element that is stored in Access?

Comment: The operator you need is `>=`. Have you tried putting quotes around the date like this: `'10-10-2016'`?

Comment: in the where clause you probably need to change question_start to `question_start.ToString()` since you have made the comparator a string

Comment: Does changing it to .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") help?

Answer (score 0):

You need proper formatting of the string expression for the date value:

```
WHERE question_start => #" & dtDateText.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#"
```